# How to configure log4net appender for fo-dicom?

Tags: c#, log4net, fo-dicom

**What's the problem?**

I cannot figure out how to set a proper file appender for logging fo-dicom request/response data. I want to log all debug-level data into text file, handled by standard RollingFileAppender configured at *log4net.config* file, but I have no idea how to connect *fo-dicom log4net connector* (from Nuget package) with my FileAppender to do so.

**What I want to achieve?**

Log all the debug data, previously printed on diagnostic console, into text file, configured by log4net.config (in the meaning of file location, message format, etc.)

**Current code :**

Here's simple connector activation, as mentioned in manual :

```
Dicom.Log.LogManager.SetImplementation(Dicom.Log.Log4NetManager.Instance);
```

And appender inside log4net.config :

```
<logger name="FileLogger">
      <appender-ref ref="file"/>
 </logger>

<appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <filter type="log4Net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
    <loggerToMatch value="FileLogger"/>
    <loggerToMatch value="MultiLogger"/>
  </filter>

(irrelevant configuration of appender)
</appender>
```

I'm little bit confused as I cannot find any example of complete working configuration of such connector.

Comment: fo-dicom has a very simple interface ILogger. the Log4netManager just creates an instance of log4net.ILog and forwards the texts (https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/blob/development/Logging/Log4Net.Desktop/Log4NetManager.cs). I am not so sure about lot4net, but maybe it's a version-thing? fo-dicom in its latest 4.0.0-rc1 uses log4net 2.0.8 for example.

Comment: And what is your error? Do you get no log at all, or any exception, or...